# Emulate an incoming call on physical device via PC (Eclipse)

Tags: android, android-emulator, eclipse-plugin

I am working on an android project, and I want to be able to test my app on a physical device. The only way I can test my app is to receive incoming text messages and calls. I know I can simulate texts and calls on the emulator either via telnet or via DDMS in Eclipse.

Is this possible to do the same thing without having to keep texting myself or calling myself from another device as its going to cost. I'd much prefer to do it on a device as it is much quicker than on the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use applications from google play like this one

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.popularapp.fakecall&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5wb3B1bGFyYXBwLmZha2VjYWxsIl0.

Comment: This seemed ideal but it unfortunately doesn't appear to trigger the broadcast receiver for the phone state which is what I need to test my app

Answer (score 0):

For text Message, there are number of online sites where you can send Free SMS(TextMessage) to your mobile. I tested in India and US and it worked. Per day, you can send around 100 SMS(TextMessage)... I tested my application through that..

Regarding the Incoming call, if you are in US, probably you can use google talk to dial your number that is free.

Hope this helps!

thanks,
Ramesh S

Comment: Thanks but based in the UK, but I'll look in the Free SMS sites

Comment: Hope this will be helpful for you, http://techcrunch.com/2008/12/10/gmail-enables-sms-messaging-from-chat/   , http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100218111831AApPssh ... If this answer is help, please accept the answer. Thanks Ramesh S