# Simulate Android SMS/Call on USB device

Tags: android

I've seen already that `ddms` allows to send fake SMS messages or init fake calls on Android emulator. However I am not using emulator for development, but only real device connected with USB cable.

In developer preferences on my device I can allow to simulate SMS messages. Everything I know about that is to connect to the device (emulator) with telnet:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

and send SMS message with

```
sms send 12345 Hello SO!
```

I cannot connect with telnet to the USB device - it just yels `connection refused`.

I had forwarded ports with adb, got into device using telnet, but after calling `sms send ...` it shows that `sms` was not found.

Back to the merits of the SMS simulating - is it even possible to send any with adb/shell from PC to the USB device ?

Comment: Refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224351/emulate-an-incoming-call-on-physical-device-via-pc-eclipse. Also this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/21445656/1972566 is kind of a hack but can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from the developer site that there is currently no support for USB connections
See this link : [SMS Emulation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#sms) under Emulator Limitations